# Is overcarbonated IPA an IPA or a different style?

Tags: ipa

I usually brew my own beer. I prefer IPA (American) to all other styles. I like more carbonated beers (with CO2 volume >4, refer to the chart -http://www.drinktanks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/CARBONATION_CHART_DRINKTANKS.png). Would an overcarbonated hoppy (IBU >70) ale qualify as an IPA or would that be a completely different style?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that an overcarbonated IPA is still an IPA. IPAs are characterized by the intense hoppy aroma, a malt backbone, and color. The carbonation level isn't referred to in style guides, generally.

- [Beer Advocate's IPA Style Guide](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/style/116/)
- [Ratebeer's IPA Style Guide](http://www.ratebeer.com/beerstyles/india-pale-ale-ipa/17/)

What I believe you're doing is creating a slightly more sour IPA. With more dissolved CO<sub>2</sub> in the beer, you're creating slight amounts of carbonic acid, and [acids make things a bit more sour](http://www.ask.com/science/acids-taste-sour-9162775ff5be382a). Seems like a pretty cool variant of an IPA, actually.